# Flat a point cloud (ply) to RGB image

Tags: python, image, rgb, open3d, ply-file-format

I am trying to convert a ply to a RGB Image.
I can extract **pcd.colors** and **pcd.points** from the file, but how I can flat it to an RGB image.

```
np.asarray(pcd.colors)
np.asarray(pcd.points)
```

My problem is the above function give me a **(1250459,3)** array and I have to convert it to **(X,Y,3)** array, But what are **X** and **Y**? **(image size)**

I am using Open3D library in python to read ply data and have access to colors or points.

Comment: I think you need to determine the size of your output image.  Then take the X value and Y value  from your 1250459 pcd.points and scale it to the height in pixels and width in pixels.  Then mapping your pcd.colors to the pixel and creating an image array.  Have you looked at adding OpenCV

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53700089/convert-xyz-point-cloud-to-grayscale-image